# How to use VC++ compiler in command line(Windows)?

Tags: c, visual-c++, cmd

I tried to use VC++ commandline, instead of MinGW compiler for windows system programming. I wrote a simple hello world program and tried to compile it, then i got this error message.

> test2.c(1): fatal error C1083:'stdio.h': No such file or directory

I also added "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\Hostx86\x86" directory (where c1.dll lives) to the System Envionment Variable(PATH).

How can I fix this issue? Other tutorials don't give much information about VC++. (A lot of MinGW compiler tutorial out there btw)

Comment: Likely you just don't have the proper environment variables set up. Try using the "Developer Command Prompt" that is install with Visual Studio as that will have the proper setup for command-line use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use visual studio command line if you want to compile or run program with the help of vc++ compiler.

[image]

Else all information related to setting environment variables ETC. resides in this [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/36k2cdd4(v=vs.90)) document.